# If And Or Statement in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with column headers that are types of support with the 3 members that these services are available to : Bronze, Silver and Gold. This is the service level offered for the applications. There are rows with applications and each application has the level of service they have paid for which is Bronze Silver and Gold. So the applications that have bronze service only get bronze support. But applications that have paid for silver get silver support and bronze support. And gold gets silver and bronze support. There are already values inside of the table, some of which MUST NOT be changed. The only values that should change are cells that have underpaid for service: such as the words PLAN-BUILD in a cell where an application has paid for bronze service, but the support is only for services that are elevated to silver level support.

```
=IF(AND(OR(L3="Silver")L3="Bronze")J25="Silver",L25, "N/A")
```

The statement is supposed to say (in English) if the application has been paid for silver support, leave the cells that have a column header of silver or bronze alone, don't change those values from what they currently are. But if the application has been paid for silver support and the cell is under a column that is offered to applications that have paid for gold service, change the cell value to "N/A".

Is it possible to do this in one string? Also, first time posting, so feedback is welcome.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! There is a lot to read here -- if you want to make it easier for us (and subsequently get more help) please edit your question to show some sample data and *what you expect the function to return* <-- that's crucial because it makes it so much clearer for us

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're just missing/misplacing your commas and brackets

```
=IF(AND(OR(L3="Silver",L3="Bronze"),J25="Silver"),L25, "N/A")
```

Or, as Jeeped pointed out:

```
=IF(AND(OR(L3={"Silver","Bronze"}),J25="Silver"),L25, "N/A")
```

Comment: You can actually write the OR section as `... OR(L3={"Silver", "Bronze"}), ...`. A hardcoded array of string literals can be used in AND or OR without CSE.

Comment: @Jeeped ... that's great!